# 'CustomUser' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to establish a user type base register/login system for my e-commerce app. I have used the following codes in my views file. here's the code snippet from my models.py. Just given the customer class as i am focusing on that first.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_choices=((1,"Merchant"),(2,"Customer"))
    user_type=models.CharField(max_length=255,choices=user_type_choices,default=1)
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = "AUTH_USER_MODEL"
class CustomerUser(models.Model):
    auth_user_id=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer', null= True,blank=True)
    name= models.CharField(max_length = 255, null= True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null=True)
    profile_pic=models.FileField(default="")
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So, as far I can say that I am logged in but can't access my home page as I got the following error.

```
TypeError at /
'CustomUser' object is not iterable
.......
 Local vars
F:\rewards\projectreward\rewardapp\userviews.py, line 152, in store
    data = cartData(request) …
Local vars
F:\rewards\projectreward\rewardapp\utils.py, line 43, in cartData
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(request.user, complete=False) …
```

I'm not sure why my cartData function in utlis.py is affected by this. It worked perfect when I didn't used user type base login. However, here's the cartData from utils.py.

```
def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(request.user, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        cookieData = cookieCart(request)
        cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
        order = cookieData['order']
        items = cookieData['items']
    return {'cartItems': cartItems, 'order': order, 'items':items}
```

my forms.py is:

```
class CustomerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):


    mob = forms.IntegerField(min_value = 0, max_value = 9000000000000)
    first = forms.CharField(max_length = 255)
    last = forms.CharField(max_length = 255)
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['first', 'last' ,'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'mob']
```

lastly the views for registration and login is as follows:

```
def customerSignUpView(request):

    form_class = CustomerSignUpForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=user.password)
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form = form_class()
            return render(request, 'usertemplates/register.html', {'form': form})

def loginUser(request):
    page = 'login'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('store')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Invalid Credentials")
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'usertemplates/login.html', {'page': page})
```

Comment: you need to set which field = request.user in get_or_create, you cannot just put argument without a key in it, it will trigger kwarg and iterate over it if they argument key is not specified

Comment: thanks. Your suggestion helped me to understand the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't get_or_create() use kwargs?  In which case you'll need something like

```
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=request.user, complete=False)
```

where 'customer' is the name of the user foreign key field in the Order model.

Edit based on comment below

```
customer_user = CustomerUser.objects.get(user = request.user)
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer_user, complete=False)
```

Comment: I used your suggestion. Now I have the error  
"Cannot query "venus": Must be "CustomerUser" instance." where venus is the username I tried to get registered.

Comment: reading between the lines, your Order model users CustomerUser not CustomUser, so we need to get that via request.user.  I've updated my answer. If this doesn't work, please include your order model;

Comment: Now I got the error, "CustomerUser matching query does not exist." it's showing on the edited answer you added.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am bothering you too much. I'm quite new to the field. I tried the whole night to debug it. One error just gave me another one.

Comment: Had another look and saw both auth_user_id and user fields are one-to-one with CustomUser. Try 'user' instead.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks. But the thing that worked for me is I had to declare the request.user as CustomerUser as the additional condition in my cart data function.

Comment: Heh. That's literally what i suggested in the first place.  Sorry if i was unclear.